# Ember-Drag-Sort: Usage of "handle" selector results in dragEnd params being passed undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-drag-sort

Whenever I assign a class selector to the "handle" selector and drag, all the params being passed to the DragEndAction are undefined my code below

```
    = drag-sort-list [
                items=sortedSections
                group='sections'
                dragEndAction=(action 'dragEnd')
                handle=".drag-handle"
            ] as | item |
```

handle code :

```
        i.material-icons.drag-handle draggable="true"
          | drag_indicator
```

which results in this error: 
[console_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAwtn.png)
*note I am using emblem template syntax

for additional context, heres what my dragEnd action looks like:

```
        dragEnd({ sourceList, sourceIndex, targetList, targetIndex }) {
          console.log(sourceList, sourceIndex, targetList, targetIndex);
          if (sourceList === targetList && sourceIndex === targetIndex) return;

          const item = sourceList.objectAt(sourceIndex)
          sourceList.removeAt(sourceIndex); 
          targetList.insertAt(targetIndex, item)
```

everything works when i take the handle selector off, unsure whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it's supposed to work:

```
{{#drag-sort-list
  items         = items
  handle        = ".handle"
  dragEndAction = (action 'dragEnd')
  as |item|
}}
  <span class="handle" draggable=true>
    [handle]
  </span>

  {{item.name}}
{{/drag-sort-list}}
```

[Working demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/a56285cc30df00673234b1ea39534280?numColumns=2&openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ccontrollers.application.js).

I've checked with the code, the `handle` parameter is not involved with invoking the action at all, and there's no way the action can be invoked with every argument as `undefined`.

My bet is that you've messed up with Emblem and provided an extra argument to the action, e. g. `(action 'dragEnd' 'foo')` instead of `(action 'dragEnd')`.

You can check if that's the case via `console.log(arguments)` in your action. Normally `arguments` should contain a single item which is a hash.

If this doesn't help, please provide a reproduction demo of your problem and I'll update my answer.

After you update your question, make sure to reply with a comment to my answer, so that I get notified.

Comment: This led me on the right track - thank you! my drag-handle was getting passed down into a contextual-container which must have been causing a 'ghost' param to be passed in. Once i moved it up into the same template as my sort-list everything worked fine.